# I'm having issues with my first Rigify rigs

Tags: animation, bones, rigify

I'm getting into animation and am testing out with blenders rigify basic meta human rig. What I'm doing is  matching as best I can the meta rig with my character model then hitting generate rig. My first issue is the generated rig. As you can see in my pictures the top half is way off, the control rig is much higher than the characters torso and there's a mess of spine bones bunched together in the characters chest and back.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And when I start moving the bones you get weird deformation that I don't see in peoples rigify tutorials.

[image]

I wanted to get a picture of how I matched the meta rig to my character but it won't let me redo till that point. So I'll redo the matching and try again and send pictures.

In the meantime does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with my setup?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: So on the help of someone on reddit I applied scale on my meta rig before generating the rig (I forgot I'd saved a copy of my blend before pressing generate) and I've gotten a much better result as seen here: https://imgur.com/qRmwjfa Dunno if it solves all my problems but it's MUCH better. I'll leave this answer up in case there's more insight I can glean from the new answers.

Comment: Hello and welcome. The comment you used and considered an answer, should be better formulated as an answer. You can answer on your own question and it would also allow the embedding/visible link of the image, helping others to understand it easier. Therefore i would highly recommend to copy the comment and post it as an answer followed by deleting the comment.